# C# renamed class reference issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

We have ASP.NET MVC application which is running on windows server machine. I have renamed classes to satisfy sonar scanning. The code deploys and runs without issue locally and in our SIT server. However, it is showing error in UAT server on windows server machine. It shows warning in event viewer that it could not find reference to previously renamed class. I have renamed a class from "CarDTO" to "CarDto", it is still trying to look for CarDTO which does not exists after the rename.

I have tried to do the following but none seems to solve the issue.

- Restart IIS
- Recycle application pools
- Clear asp.net temporary folder
- Increase the version in assembly info

I used the same files and dll in both SIT and UAT servers.

Anyone has similar issue and a way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: clear browser maybe?

Comment: Have you determined where exactly the invalid reference is being made?

Comment: Clean your solution and rebuild project.

Comment: Is the calss CarDTO a separate .cs file? I think the name is CarDTO.cs when you create the class at first. When you change the class to CarDto, but the file name didnot change, so it still look for reference CarDTO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Apparently, there is an extra dll that accidentally being copied to the bin folder. Even though it is not being used, it gets compiled by IIS and complaining that class name mismatched.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).